# How can you obtain the full URL of a HTTP triggered Logic App in the Azure Portal, if you can't use the designer?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How can you obtain the full URL of a HTTP triggered Logic App in the Azure Portal, **if you can't use the designer?**

Usually if I create a logic app with the HTTP trigger, after the first time I save it, the "Designer" has the full URL, including the `sig`, and even an option to "Copy Url", e.g.

```
https://prod.northeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/.../paths/invoke?...&sig=xxxxxxx
```

But if I create a logic app in the "Code view" with multiple triggers, e.g. one for GET, one for POST, I can't switch to the "Designer".

**So how can I get the full URL?**

*... without using e.g. PowerShell and the Az cmdlets, e.g.*

```
Get-AzLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl 
  -ResourceGroupName $(LogicAppResourceGroupName) 
  -Name $(LogicAppName-ProcessData) 
  -TriggerName "manual"
```

Comment: What about rest api [listcallbackurl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/listcallbackurl)?

Comment: @georgechen Nice idea ... didn't know that. But it's either, not going to work, or be a pain to sort out in current office, as we're very locked down ... just have the browser + Portal, no dev tools

Comment: Just use the `Try it` button in the rest description page.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Nice idea ... just tried it and the sign in goes to ... Status Code: 500; Internal Server Error     :-(

Comment: So you don't wat to use Az just don't have the tool, so do you mind run az with the cloud shell in the portal.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview

Comment: @GeorgeChen Yeap, can't get easy access to PowerShell. And that's a neat way to do it, and even better, I've just tried it and SUCCESS !!   Please add this as an answer and I'll accept and upvote it. And many thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually Logic app http trigger endpoint URL is a [sas URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app) with below format:

```
https://<request-endpoint-URI>sp=<permissions>sv=<SAS-version>sig=<signature>
```

And you don't have dev tool, the efficient ways are the REST API:[listcallbackurl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/listcallbackurl) and the Az command:[Get-AzLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/get-azlogicapptriggercallbackurl?view=azps-3.8.0).

The rest api description provides a simple way to test the API with `Try it` button, just log in without additional `auth token` generation.

Also Azure Portal provides the [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) to use the PowerShell and Bash command to manage Azure resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the `Run Trigger` button and select the `Run with payload` buttons in the code view, you can get the full url from the pane that pops up, with a convenient button to copy the full url.

[image: "Run with payload" dialog in logic apps code view in Azure Portal]